# js devexpress PieChart Series color runtime

Tags: javascript, devexpress, chart.js, pie-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

I am working on [js.devexpress Pie Chart](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/Pie/jQuery/Light/). I'd like to change the series color at runtime.

I am fetching data from webservice and as per my logic i have to change color red or green as per value. if value is less then 0 [Zero] then Pie Color is red else green.

My code is

```
 <div id="canvas-holder" >       
    <div id="pie" ></div>
</div>
```

```
 var pie =   $("#pie").dxPieChart({
        size: {width: 500},
        //palette: "bright",
        dataSource: [{country: "On",area: 0}],
        series: [{argumentField: "country", valueField: "area"}],
        title: "Area of Countries"             
    }).dxPieChart("instance");

    setInterval(function () {
        debugger;
        pie.option("Color", "red");

        pie.element().css({ Color: 'red' })

        var chartOptions = pie.option();
        pie.series[0].Color = "red";
        pie.option(chartOptions);

    }, 1000);
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution I found : visit devexpress support forum for [More Details](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T635700/piechart-how-to-customize-series-color-at-runtime)

[Sample Code Download link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/cb85320e-8076-4922-b6de-1f44ea748eb1)

Code is

```
<div id="canvas-holder">
    <div id="pie"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var ds = [{ country: "On", area: 0 }];

    var pie = $("#pie").dxPieChart({
        size: { width: 500 },
        //palette: "bright",
        dataSource: ds,
        series: [{ argumentField: "country", valueField: "area" }],
        title: "Area of Countries",
        customizePoint: function (pointInfo) {
            if (pointInfo.value <= 0) {
                return {
                    color: "red"
                }
            }
            return {
                color: "green"
            }
        }
    }).dxPieChart("instance");

    var isVal = 0;

    setInterval(function () {           

        if (isVal == 0)
            isVal = 1;
        else
            isVal = 0;

        ds[0].area = 1;

        pie.option("dataSource", ds);

    }, 1000);

</script>
```